# characters like æ ø å ö ä ü for display in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, query, meta-tags

When I display **Danish/Norwegian characters** like **"æ ø å"**, the current character and the rest of the text in that field are gone in magento (Magento ver. 1.9.3.2).

**Example for::**

Input filed:

**"FJORD [F-YOR], barskog, bryter fosser og rikelig frukt foredle drama av de norske fjordene. Våre diffusorer bringe subtile og stabil duft til ditt hjem i ukesvis."**

Output

**"FJORD [F-YOR], barskog, bryter fosser og rikelig frukt foredle drama av de norske fjordene. V"**

[image]

[image]

For solution, I've added meta tag in header file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'/>
```

but it's not working.

**Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.**

Comment: Only using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` should work.

Comment: @Jaimin Sutariya :thank for suggestion but it's not work for me.

Comment: Are you using flat product catalog? If so have you checked the data in the flat catalog and eav tables to make sure it is the same?

Comment: @DhavalDave this is related to mysql character set while reading the data from db. Can you see the data being saved in db properly ?

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is related to mysql character set of your table. Please check stored data in your database.
If data has same problem like the frontend, you should alter your table to "**utf8-unicode-ci**" or "**utf8-general-ci**" instead. Then input data again.

Good luck!